# How can I override Looker's always_filter default filter on LookerStudio?

Tags: looker-studio, looker

We've enabled Looker Connection on LookerStudio and I'm trying to use data from a Looker Explore. I find that the data is limited to 7 days because there is a default 7 days filter using always_filter when the Explore is defined in Looker. Thus limiting the data I can pull to only show 7 days of data.

I can override the default filter when I pull the Explore using Looker (i.e. I can filter to include more dates) but I am not able to do the same in LookerStudio.  Has anyone come across this issue and can help to resolve it?

Thanks